# If I capture a Gold Skulltula while replaying a mission, do I have to fully recomplete the mission to keep it?

Tags: hyrule-warriors

It would be nice if one could just grab the thing and go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, yes. Wish there was an easier way but I guess it's just part of the challenge.